# LinearSVC missing in Apache Spark 2.1? Non-Linear Kernels in Spark 2.2?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, svm

Can you please confirm (or refute) the following two statements?

1. Support for Support Vector Machines on SparkML (not talking about RDD based implementation) is only available since Apache Spark V2.2.0 (since it appears in the 2.2 API doc only https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/Classifier.html
2. Support for Support Vector Machines on SparkML currenty doesn't support non-linear classifiers using kernels (again, not talking about the RDD based implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `LinearSVC` is available just from **spark 2.2+** but it's still experimental :
   https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/LinearSVC.scala#L72
2. Kernel functionalities to SVM Classifier to find non linear patterns is still a task in progress but no one seems to be working on it now. You can follow it's progress at this link :
   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4638